# how to undo changes made in run configuration

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a new run configuration `config_1` and it was working fine till yesterday.

Today when I changed the name of the project to `project_2` the old project name *in the run config -> classpath -> user entries* `project_1` seems to be closed and by mistake I deleted it.

Now I can't run the program due to the `class not found` exception. If i even add the project by clicking *advanced -> add projects* the program is not running correctly.

How can I run the program or how can I add the project?

Or if I even undo the changes made through `local history` will that actually undo changes made in run config?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have deleted the `Run Configurations`, there's no way to get it back.

To answer your question, why `Run Configurations` for `project_2` does not work?

The reason might because you failed to specify the correct project name.

In the following screenshot, the project name is `Test`.  You need to make sure the project name in the Configurations (project_2) matches the actual project name.

[image]

Comment: Even if I'm still on "Run Configurations" window a while after I accidently deleted it? :)

Answer (score 1):

And to get a bit more saftey you might export the launch configs to the file system by using the "Common" Tab and the "Save As" section. Then you can commit the config to the repository.